# java - find out the type of class which implements of other classes

Tags: java, class, instance

I have a kind of specific problem, let's say, that I have

```
public interface A {
}

//------------------------------

public class B implements A {

    static int countx = 0;
}

//----------------------------------
public class C implements A {

    static int county = 0;
}

//----------------------------------

public class Arc {

    public A from;
    public A to;

//========================================
```

and now I have an object a (which is an instance of Arc) and I want to find out whether it is an instance of B or C and get to the atributes countX or countY (stg like a.from.countX)
any ideas? :)

Comment: There is no relation between the classes `Arc` and `A` in your hierarchy.

Comment: Are you sure you have two A's in Arc?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use instanceof to solve this issue

as in

```
if(a instanceof B) return a.countx
if(a instanceof C) return a.county
```

Comment: This won't work without a typecast. (Or actually in this case it will, because `countx` and `county` are both static, which is probably an error/misunderstanding from OPs side.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `instanceof` and a typecast:

```
if (a.from instanceof B) {
    B b = (B)a.from;
    b.countx;
}
```

Edit: But you should really not need such a thing! If you do, you can probably redesign it to not produce ugly code like this.

For example you could let your interface `A` have a method `getCount()` and let your classes B and C implement these, by returning `countx` or `county`.

Edit2: I just noticed that your `countx` and `county` members are `static`! Why would you do that? `static` means, that they don't "act" upon instances of your class but on your class object (they are "class members"). This means that you can access and modify these variables *everywhere* by accessing them through `A.countx` or `B.county`; you most probably don't want this, because multiple instances of class `A` will *share* the same `countx`!

Comment: So... it could be used for counting the number of instances of that specific class.

Comment: It could, if you increment the variable after creating a new instance (which you can do in the constructor) and if you don't make the variable public. The last one is important, because if you don't do this, some random class can just say `B.countx = -5;` and now you have -5 instances of your class (not really of course). That's why there is member encapsulation.

Comment: Sure, but it is short sample code. Your comment sounds if there is no use for static members / shared state whatsoever. Btw the members are not public in the sample code.

Comment: I never meant to say that static members are useless, I only meant to say that since he accesses this members through an _instance_ of the class, he probably doesn't intend them to be static in the first place. Also, not having any access modifier is still very strong, as it means package access; so every random class in the package can access it and there's nothing preventing a class from just saying it is part of the package.

Answer (score 1):

Your current design is not good from the OOP standpoint. You need some encapsulation and polymorphism. In an OOP language, you don't explicitly **check** for the type of an object, you arrange for that to happen automatically via dynamic dispatch. So whatever data you need from both B and C, add a method to the interface A that will get that data and then implement the method in B and C accordingly. Also, don't use public instance fields, that breaks encapuslation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object that is an instance of Arc, then how is it also an instance of B or C?  I feel like your code is flawed and needs restructuring.  For example, as Tudor pointed out, "There is no relation between the classes Arc and A in your hierarchy."

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to have information about the classes :

```
getClass().getSuperclass()
```

Regards, 
Erwald

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this :

*What makes me want to discriminate between a B and a C ?*  Is it an operation?  If so, just implement those operations appropriately in B vs C and let dynamic dispatch take care of the rest.

```
interface Operation { 
    public Result operate(String[] args);
}

class A implements Operation { 

    @Override
    public Result operate(String[] args) { 
        //I need to do some special calculations for an A...           
        for(String arg : args) { 

        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

class B implements Operation { 

    @Override
    public Result operate(String[] args) { 
        //i know this does nothing so return the empty result
        return Result.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

Resist the tempation to use `instanceof`.  In most cases you don't need it - and its not OO.